# Como converter JsonObject em uma classe java

Tags: java, android, mobile

Saudações a todos,

Estou desenvolvendo um app que pega o retorno de um webservice para ser utilizado nesse aplicativo como dados de login entre outros.
Gostaria de pedir a orientação de vocês sobre a melhor forma de converter os dados que estão em um objeto JsonObject para uma classe que armazena todas essas informações de retorno da API.

O json tem a estrutura abaixo:

```
{
"token": "N02156564365034657289&(*&*&$#",
"success": true,
"timezone": "America/Bahia",
"user": {
    "name": "Fulano de roça",
    "email": "fulano@email.com",
    "photo": ""
},
"msg": "Autenticado com sucesso"
```

}

Eu criei uma classe para receber os dados com base nesse json acima:

```
public class RetornoServer {

private String mToken;
private boolean mSuccess;
private Usuario mUser;
private String mMsg;

public RetornoServer() {
}

public RetornoServer(String Token, boolean Success, Usuario User, String Msg) {
    this.mToken = Token;
    this.mSuccess = Success;
    this.mUser = User;
    this.mMsg = Msg;
}

public String getmToken() {
    return mToken;
}

public void setmToken(String mToken) {
    this.mToken = mToken;
}

public boolean ismSuccess() {
    return mSuccess;
}

public void setmSuccess(boolean mSuccess) {
    this.mSuccess = mSuccess;
}

public Usuario getmUser() {
    return mUser;
}

public void setmUser(Usuario mUser) {
    this.mUser = mUser;
}

public String getmMsg() {
    return mMsg;
}

public void setmMsg(String mMsg) {
    this.mMsg = mMsg;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RetornoServer{" +
            "mToken='" + mToken + '\'' +
            ", mSuccess=" + mSuccess +
            ", mUser=" + mUser +
            ", mMsg='" + mMsg + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Eu estou usando o Retrofit 2 na conexão com o webservice e o retorno está vindo tudo certinho, isso já alimentando o objeto JsonObject como mostra abaixo:

```
JsonObject responseJson = response.body();
```

Tentei fazer a conversão usando o Gson, mas não deu certo

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
RetornoServer retornoServer = gson.fromJson(responseJson, RetornoServer.class);
```

Em fim, se possível gostaria da orientação de vocês sobre algum material que eu deva ler ou alguma sugestão. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Vou te passar o link de um site que eu sempre utilizo quando quero fazer isso, é bem simples, basta colar o Json e ele te retorna a classe Java, no entanto ele utiliza as anotações da biblioteca JacksonAnnotations.
Segue o link: [Json Schema to Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Por que não funcionou? Qual o erro?

Comment: @nullptr o erro na verdade é que os campos todos ficaram com valor nulos.

Comment: @JorgeDiego muito obrigado, vou olhar esse site para ver se consigo resolver. Se não conseguir, vou ter que alimentar ou atribuir os valores dos objetos na mão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson é uma das muitas bibliotecas que convertem JSON em objetos. No seu caso, seus atributos estão todos nulos porque não foi possível encontrar os campos do seu objeto com os nomes dos campos do JSON. Por exemplo:

```
public class RetornoServer {

private String token;
private boolean success;
private Usuario user;
private String msg;
(...)
```

Mais informações [aqui](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-parse-json-to-java/) (retirado do próprio repositório do Gson). Você pode reparar que quando os atributos do JSON tem underline (`_`), os atributos do Objeto Java também tem.

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta! Realmente você identificou onde eu errei e o site que você enviou o link tirou outras dúvidas que tinha.